# NetworkManager run script before connection based on SSID

Tags: wireless, networking, scripts, network-manager

Is it possible to have NetworkManager run a script before it connects to a wifi network and pass the SSID of the network to the script (or just execute a script based on SSID)? I'm switching back from WICD and am sorely missing this ability. I googled around but all I could find is `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/*` which seems to execute *after* the connection is established and doesn't pass the SSID.

Comment: How about `/etc/network/if-up.d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old seemingly unsanwered... filling in the blank.

/etc/network/if-up.d 
-> pre-up option

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/interfaces.5.html